# WordPress theme files within a subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

Working on a current project where there is a github repo for specific theme files. When I clone down the repo it puts the theme folder within a separate directory (as it should) for example:

`/wp-content/themes/projectfolder/themefolder`

What I'm wondering is if it's possible to have WordPress look for that theme within a subdirectory without having to move the entire git project into the `themes` folder since that's going to make a mess of things.

Comment: Wordpress had the register_theme_directory() function: https://codex.wordpress.org/register_theme_directory

Answer (score 0):

In your wp-config.php file add the following just as follows:

```
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
register_theme_directory('/wp-content/themes/projectfolder');
```

Typically the [register_theme_directory();](https://codex.wordpress.org/register_theme_directory) function is used to define a themes folder inside a plugin, however, there is some good use cases outside of that.